# The process has been signaled with signal "11"

Tags: php

[image]

Any idea what I can do to get around this error? every application works perfectly, except when I try to download a file where `dompdf` is called to generate the "certificate". It is an online course school application.

`config/app.php`

```
*/

'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),

/*
```

Permissions in all files, are okay.

Comment: On common flavors of Unix, signal 11 is SIGSEGV, a segmentation fault.  Generally speaking, it means that the process receiving it attempted to access memory that does not belong to it.  And that is symptomatic of a flaw in the program.  We would need to review a [mre] to advise you on where the error is/  What you have presented does not include one.

Comment: The tag`assets` on its own doesn't really mean anything. If this is Laravel you should tag with that

Comment: Since PHP is entirely memory managed, the error can only occur in one of its C extensions. It's likely that the PHP installation, or the installation of one of its extensions, is broken. Since you mention PDFs, check what extensions that PDF library uses and try re-installing them.